# How to enforce withColumn to work chronological row after row?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I have algorithm that depend in the order of the arriving data, it's reflected in the order of the data frame rows .

Row 0 - t_0 | Row 1 - t_1 | .... | Row N - t_N

my code :

```
df_res=df.withColumn('algo_res',temporalAlgo_UDF(F.col('value')))
```

How I can enforce the executor to apply the algorithm row after row (without parallelism ) ?

Thanks,

MAK

Answer (score 0):

You could try `df.coalesce(1).withColumn...`

from [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrame.coalesce):

> *However, if you're doing a drastic coalesce, e.g. to numPartitions =
> 1, this may result in your computation taking place on fewer nodes
> than you like
>
> (e.g. **one node in the case of numPartitions = 1** ).*